# How to add extra columns in multi-series Column Chart in FusionCharts

Tags: fusioncharts

I want to show few Bars in the Begining of the graph Which should be excluded in multi-series Column Chart,

Like (A1,A2,A3,A4), Q1(CurrentYear, PreviousYear), Q2(CurrentYear, PreviousYear), Q3(CurrentYear, PreviousYear), Q4(CurrentYear, PreviousYear)

Assuming A1,A2,A3,A4 are Bars to be shown first, Then Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 are the categories as usual for the multi-Series Column Chart.

I'm using the XML code right now as follows,

```
 <chart caption="Sales in Last Two Years" subcaption="Quarter-wise comparison" xaxisname="Quarter" yaxisname="Sales (In USD)" numberprefix="$" theme="fint">
<categories>
<category label="Q1" />
<category label="Q2" />
<category label="Q3" />
<category label="Q4" />
</categories>
<dataset seriesname="Previous Year">
<set value="10000" />
<set value="11500" />
<set value="12500" />
<set value="15000" />
</dataset>
<dataset seriesname="Current Year">
<set value="25400" />
<set value="29800" />
<set value="21800" />
<set value="26800" />
</dataset>
</chart>
```

I want to display Four columns as first four column , which should not be the part of multi-series Column Chart.

How can it be done?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Is your requirement similar to the attached image?

Comment: Yes Exactly, I am able to populate similar graph now but the problem is X-Axis Labels will not appear exactly under the respective Bar's.